# Which is more correct: "burgled" or "burglarized"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, american-english, past-participles

Which is more correct:

> We were *burgled* yesterday.

or

> We were *burglarized* yesterday.

I'm from the U.K. and never use *burglarized* but my friend from the U.S.A. seems to think it's OK.

Comment: I forget where I read it, but someone once wrote that "Originally, a house that had been stoled from had been burgled, and the person who did it was a burglar. The American fondness for long names turned burgled into burglarised, and, inevitably, the person who did it became a burglariser." I'm with you on this, and so is the spelling checked as I type this in...

Comment: I would note that the term 'burglar' is more common than 'burglariser' in the US.  In fact, I've never heard anyone use the term 'burglariser'.  Then again, I don't work in law enforcement...

Comment: @Brian whoever wrote that was wrong. Originally, one who stole from a house was a burglar. Both "burgle" and "burglarize" were new words coined from "burglar" around the same time—the 1870s. Each one became popular in different places, but there is no reason to believe that one is "better" than the other in terms of etymological "purity" or historical precedent.

Comment: In fact, if you wanted to make an argument you might say that "burglarize" is more regular because -ize is the way you form verbs from nouns. "Burgle" is a corruption because the word "burglar" came first, and its -ar is not the agentive -er as in "writer", "toaster", etc. The presupposition that it is based on the previously nonexistent verb "burgle" would therefore be an error. If it were, "burglar" would have had the spelling "burgler", which it does not.

Comment: The word "burglarized" sounds hilarious. I mean c'mon. That's not a real word!

Comment: @nohat and now the person who was robbed will be a victim of a "burglarization" and the robber will be a "burglarizator" ;-)

Comment: @HarryWood: "Burglarized" is more common than "burgled" in the US. In fact, "burglarized" gets more Google hits. The [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burglarized%2C+burgled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=30) shows them more or less tied with burglarized now having a comfortable lead. (Because AmEng dominates the corpus, [BrEng](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burglarized%2Cburgled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=30) shows the reverse.)

Comment: As a Brit, I just want to add that it's extremely pervasive for British people to say that American forms are "wrong" or "less correct", even if they would accept forms from Scotland, Ireland, Australia, Jamaica, Trinidad, etc. I guess it's historical.

Comment: “More correct”? I’d fix that first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either is acceptable. *Burglarized* is much more common in the USA, although *burgled* is less cumbersome. Dictionary.com dates both [*burgle*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burgle) and [*burglarize*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burglarize) from the 1870s. *Burgle* is a back-formation from *burglar*.

Comment: I would say that "burgle" is *more* cumbersome if you say it in the US, since people aren't used to hearing it and might not realize what you said.

Comment: True. I just meant in terms of (unnecessary) syllables.

Comment: @Kelly C Hess: That is true, although I would say they are a worthwhile expense for clarity (hey, syllables are cheap :).

Comment: Hey, I love a bargain. :)

Comment: Burglarize and burgle are clearly both different ways to verb burglar. If they both date from the 1870's, they were likely coined independently.

Comment: The most salient point here is that *burgle* is a back-formation from *burglar* (note it's burglAr not burglEr, which is how you would spell a word that means "one who burgles").

Comment: [This chart of ***written*** usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burgle%2Cburglarize&year_start=1979&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=10) strongly suggests that within a few decades, plain ***burgle*** will have overtaken ***burglarize*** even in AmE (the latter never had any currency in BrE). Given that written usage normally lags behind ***spoken*** usage (which I can't chart), I wouldn't be surprised to learn that this usage shift has *already* led to the shorter version being more common in younger Americans' speech today.

Answer (score 7):

I really like Google's N-gram viewer. Look how a picture says more on the subject than a thousand books could :)

*Burgled* vs. *burglarized* in Google's corpus of British English:
[British http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=burgle%2Cburglarize&corpus=6&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=burgle%2Cburglarize&corpus=6&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000)

*Burgled* vs. *burglarized* in Google's corpus of American English:
[image: American]
<sub>(source: [googlelabs.com](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=burgle%2Cburglarize&corpus=5&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burgle) *burglarize* is an acceptable US synonym to *burgle*.

Answer (score 2):

A deleted answer made a distinction that was already in my mind...

> While both are clearly acceptible in the U.S., nobody has pointed out the distinction in meaning that I perceive: Thieves burgle. Houses are burglarized. That is, burglarize is a form which is predominantly used in the passive tense.

...and supplied what I see as plausible evidence in favour of that distinction. Counting google hits...

**The house was burglarized** gets 76000.

**The house was burgled** gets 21700, giving a ratio of 3.5 for the passive.

**burglarized the house** gets 18200.

**burgled the house**  gets 11500, giving a ratio of only 1.6 for the active.

I know it's commonly said here that Google hits can be misleading, but in this case I fail to see how such a significant change in ratio can be ignored across so many results. Either some Americans make the distinction, or Brits are over twice as likely as Americans to report the burglary by saying what the burglar did (as opposed to Americans reporting the same event by saying what happened to the house). An unlikely US/UK difference, given an Englishman's home is his castle!

Though I'm a Brit who normally uses the shorter word, *the house being burglarised* (my spelling!) sounds fine. But I think it sounds distinctly odd to speak of someone *burglarising the house*.

Comment: Isn't a 'UK speaker' some sort of politician? As a British (-English) speaker, I tend to follow UK usage

Comment: @TimLymington: Mix & match, I guess. On EL&U at least, I tend to think I'm a Brit as opposed to Yank, in UK not US, and the language difference is British not American usage. But I'm not necessarily consistent.

Comment: Seems backwards. The house got burgled. They caught the crew burglarizing the ATMs. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+burgled%2C+got+burglarized&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3

Comment: @PhilSweet: I think all your chart proves is that a significant percentage of AmE speakers still use ***burglarized***. Most BrE speakers would only ever use the longer verb in facetious / affected contexts anyway, and there's no doubt [it's a declining usage in AmE too.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burgled%2Cburglarized&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=10)